# Python - How to dynamically get the class instance and return type

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, typing

Currently, I have below Python inherited class structure and created the small factory class to get the instance of the child class as below.

Here I wanted suggestions

1. Is this a good approach or any better way to implement this?
2. Inside the `PersonFacotry` class in `create` method, as of now, I am setting the return type as
   `Any`, Is it possible to dynamically return the type as `Engineer` or `Doctor` ?

```
from typing import Any


class Person: pass


class Engineer(Person): pass


class Doctor(Person): pass


class PersonFactory:
    class_mapper = {'engineer': Engineer, 'doctor': Doctor}

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, type: str) -> Any:
        return cls.class_mapper[type]


doctor_instance = PersonFactory().create('doctor')()
engineer_instance = PersonFactory().create('engineer')()
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You're not actually creating instances anywhere. `doctor_instance` isn't an instance of `Doctor`. It's just `Doctor`.

Comment: And you called the first argument of `create` `cls`, but that method is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: self is not a keyword in Python. self is a parameter in function and the user can use a different parameter name in place of it. Although it is advisable to use self because it increases the readability of code.

Comment: @user2357112 to me works even with `@classmethod` decorator

Comment: @user2357112,  Thank you corrected them and edited my question as well

Comment: did you have a look at here ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285032/9877065 ... I'd say that your approach is quite interesting and may be useful for static analysis. But if we accept PEPs as a source of an explanation for the current annotation paradigm, the highlighted text explains why return type can't be defined dynamically at the time the function is called.

Comment: on this line you could add to `create` a line like `cls.create.__annotations__["return"] = ...` using the wanted type, but the it will be rewritten each time you create a new Person subclass instance

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is actually a good approach. In fact, it is very readable and quickly comprehensible!
And yes, you can substitute `Any` with `Person`:

```py
class PersonFactory:
    def create(cls, type: str) -> Person:
        return class_mapper[type]
```

Answer (score -1):

to recap:

code 1:

```
from typing import Any

class Person:pass

class Engineer(Person):pass

class Doctor(Person):pass


doctor_instance = Doctor()
engineer_instance = Engineer()

print(doctor_instance,type(doctor_instance), type(doctor_instance).__bases__)

print(engineer_instance, type(engineer_instance), type(engineer_instance).__bases__)
```

output:

```
<__main__.Doctor object at 0x7f28eedeb4c0> <class '__main__.Doctor'> (<class '__main__.Person'>,)
<__main__.Engineer object at 0x7f28eecf6d90> <class '__main__.Engineer'> (<class '__main__.Person'>,)
```

code 2:

```
from typing import Any

class Person:pass

class Engineer(Person):pass

class Doctor(Person):pass



class PersonFactory:
    class_mapper = {'engineer': Engineer,'doctor': Doctor}
    
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, tipo: str) -> Any:
        return cls.class_mapper[tipo]()

doctor_instance = PersonFactory().create('doctor')
engineer_instance = PersonFactory().create('engineer')

print(doctor_instance, type(doctor_instance), type(doctor_instance).__bases__)

print(engineer_instance, type(engineer_instance), type(engineer_instance).__bases__)
```

output:

```
<__main__.Doctor object at 0x7fe7ac5647f0> <class '__main__.Doctor'> (<class '__main__.Person'>,)
<__main__.Engineer object at 0x7fe7ac564550> <class '__main__.Engineer'> (<class '__main__.Person'>,)
```

Code 2 should do for

> How to dynamically get the class instance

about the

> return type

```
def create(cls, tipo: str) -> class_mapper[tipo]:
```

raises `NameError: name 'tipo' is not defined`

and `mypy code2.py`  gives :

```
error: Variable "code2.PersonFactory.class_mapper" is not valid as a type
```

Not an expert in Python, annotations even less, I found this on SO:

[Is it possible to reference function parameters in Python's function annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284524/is-it-possible-to-reference-function-parameters-in-pythons-function-annotation/51285032#51285032)

I am not sure is related but states:

> Annotations must be valid expressions that evaluate without raising exceptions at the time the function is defined (but see below for forward references).
>
> Annotations should be kept simple or static analysis tools may not be able to interpret the values. For example, dynamically computed types are unlikely to be understood. (This is an intentionally somewhat vague requirement, specific inclusions and exclusions may be added to future versions of this PEP as warranted by the discussion.)
>
> I'd say that your approach is quite interesting and may be useful for static analysis. But if we accept PEPs as a source of an explanation for the current annotation paradigm, the highlighted text explains why return type can't be defined dynamically at the time the function is called.